# Function declarations in Jquery. What the action of the caractere ':'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm newbie in JavaScript and i want to understand how works some functions declarations in jquery

For example:

```
function($){
    functionA{}
    functionB{}

    return{
        init: function{
            this.functionC();
            this.functionD();
       },

       functionC: function(){
          //code function here
       },

       functionD: function(){
         //code function here
       },
    };
}(jQuery)
```

What means the use of ':' in this functions? Do you have some material explain this?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: It has nothing to do with the functions themselves `{ prob: value }` is how to assign an property a value for a object literal.

Comment: That's [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) notation. It has nothing at all to do with jQuery. Also, unrelated to the `:`, the outer function declaration as shown is invalid syntax: you'd need to have `var someVar = function($) { ...`

Comment: Ok, Thanks! In the example, the functions 'C' e 'D' could be declared out of 'return' (keeping the same result) ? @nnnnnn

Comment: If you declare C and D the same way as A and B then they wouldn't be part of the object being returned from the outer function, so the result would not be the same.

Answer (score 0):

: is the separator for the name of the property of the object {} returned by the function.
return {};

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics)